# Redirect from Axios Interceptor with NextJS 13 App Directory

Tags: next.js, axios

Has anyone found a solution to using axios interceptors with NextJS 13? I feel like it should be pretty straight forward, but it is definitely not.

A simple client component:

```
"use client"
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axiosInterceptorInstance from '@/lib/request'

interface Device {
    ...
}

export default function DevicesHolder() {
    const [devices, setDevices] = useState<Device[]>([])

    axiosInterceptorInstance.get('/api/v1/staff-admin/devices?page=1&itemsPerPage=20').then((res) => {
        setDevices(res.data.data)
    })

    return (
        <>
            {devices.map((device, key) => (
                <div key={key}>
                    <h1>{device.imei}</h1>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

And my axios interceptor:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

const axiosInterceptorInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL, // Replace with your API base URL
});

axiosInterceptorInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        // Modify the response data here
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      // Handle response errors here
      // if unathorized, redirect to login
      console.log("server", typeof window === 'undefined')
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            redirect('/login')
        }
  
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
  
export default axiosInterceptorInstance;
```

Somehow, the request runs on both the server and the client. It fails to redirect on either and throws the NEXT_REDIRECT error (which is supposed to happen??). Any ideas?

Edit 1: I should note that I tried using window.location.href, but it obviously throws an error when it runs on the server.

Comment: well next/navigation is also a Client Side hook, if your interceptor also run on server it won't work, did you try to import dynamically  the Axios interceptor to run only on the client side ?

Comment: @ShueiYang Are you suggesting I use next/dynamic to import it? If so, that only works for components. Good thought though! I appreciate it!

Comment: @ShueiYang I understand what you mean. I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ShueiYang commented, dynamically importing it was the solution to have it solely run on the client side. Here's example usage in a component (the component was a client component)

```
    const interceptor = (await import('@/lib/request')).default
    const { data } = await interceptor.post('/api/v1/staff-admin/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
```